# How can I check the sub-directories size line by line in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How can I check the sub-directories size line by line and copy the directory having size greater than 5 GB to another location?

I have to copy a large directory to S3 with the encryption but in my directory, there is few files having size greater than 5 GB.

I have to copy them in separate directory and will send it in chunks.

I am stuck in searching for particular files during the copying process and separate.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this:

l=$(ls -l | wc -l )
for (( i = 1 ; i <= l; i++ ))
do
bigfile=$(find -size +5G -exec du -sh {} \;)
echo "$bigfile"
done

but it is showing all the files in every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to move the large sub-directories of the current directory to /tmp/:

```
for f in `du -d 1 | awk '{if($1 > 5000000000) print $2}'`; do mv $f /tmp; done
```

In detail:

`du -d 1` - lists sizes of subdirectories (depth = 1)

`awk ...`: filter the sizes (column 1) and prints the matching dir names (column 2)

`for f in ...; do mv;...` : iterate over the chosen sub dirs and move only them

Comment: Thanks for the support, but somehow it is not working .
It is not copying anything to /tmp.

Comment: @KhalidWaseem Try the command step by step. 
What does "du -d 1" alone print?
Then, what does "du -d 1 | awk '{if($1 > 5000000000) print $2}'" alone prints?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too,
If I run "du -d 1" it shows directories with size in bytes.
If I run whole command then nothing it display.
If I change '5000000000' to '5G' then it will display the directories of size 5G to 5.9G not more than that.

Comment: The whole command shouldn't display anything (mv command has no output). But the large dirs should have been moved to the target location. Have the over-5GB directories actually move?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support,
I found one solution for my quer.
I did this:

```
bigfiles=$(find . -type f -size +5G)
for file in $bigfiles
 do
  cp -rf $file /tmp/upload/
done
```

It is solving my problem.
But now I want to apply an "if" condition to perform this operation whenever it meets the condition during the file copy.